# how to get .mobileprovision file and .app file

Tags: ios, xcode, .app, mobileprovision

I am new to the iphone development.

And i am using Hackintosh and i do not have any user ID of apple.

Now my clients need two file( .mobileprovision file and .app file) for creating ad hoc distribution.

Now is it possible to create .mobileprovision file and .app file from my hackintosh?

Is it mandatory of real mac and apple User ID for creating these two file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: These links are old and now point to an archive, but unfortunately the images aren't archived. The information is likely outdated and no longer relevant.

In order to provision an app you will have to be part of the [iPhone developer program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/). Once you do that, [these instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20111030040644/http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/building-devices-iphoneipad) (minus the part about building for corona) will help you. You can also [build with Xcode 4](https://web.archive.org/web/20150419124556/http://diaryofacodemonkey.ruprect.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/). I don't know if any of this can be done with a Hackintosh.

Comment: The 'these instructions' page is 403'd

Comment: hi, your link is broken

Comment: Sorry, I've updated them for an archived version but I'd look elsewhere for more current information on this topic.